# Reading Android camera device from native code, without root

Tags: android, permissions, camera, v4l2

I am working on an Android application that acquires camera frames using Video for Linux 2 APIs from /dev/videoN, where N is an integer starting from 0, such as /dev/video1, /dev/video2, etc.  I am doing this in C/C++ for performance reasons; I cannot do sufficient fast camera frame processing in Java.  The problem I am running into is that  by default the /dev/videoN devices have Unix file permission of owner and group read/write only, and thus I need to do

chmod a+rxw /dev/video1

to allow my program to be able to read from /dev/video1.  This is only doable on a rooted device.

Is there a way to allow native code to access /dev/videoN on non-rooted Android devices?  I tried to give my application the Android permissions to access the camera hardware (in AndroidManifest.xml) but that has no effect in this scenario and I still have no Unix permission by default to read from /dev/videoN.

(On Nexus 7 running Android 4.4, the /dev/videoN belongs to the Unix group "camera", but apps with the camera permissions do not seem to be placed in that group by default)

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? Accessing the device from native code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a JNI glue to access camera through java code. You can do the frame processing in native code.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the JNI overhead, as camera frame rates are sensitive to such overhead